# Insert image in mail merge (word 2007) using C# asp.nt?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, mailmerge

I'm working on a project, which requires an image on mail merge document along with other fields. 
I've done all other work(i.e inserting field data from sql) only inserting image part is remaining. 
I'm using SQL server for data source. 
My question has two parts: 
(1). How to store image in SQL, (2). and then mail merge.

Is it only way to store path of image in SQL .?

Comment: similar question asked roughly a bazillion times before. please search...

Comment: A better option would be to create a Path field on your table, where you store the path to a filelocation where the image is.

Answer (score 0):

1) Storing an image in a database table is valid but doing so you might unnecessary inflict performance and disk space issues while gaining better data integrity (your backup and migration can be a bit easier). The preferred way in most cases is, like Max said, to create some kind of an (image) identifier (file path) that allows a selection/identification of image file on the disk. In most cases storing images on a disk is a better option.

2) You have several options for mail merge. Absolutely do not use Office COM in a server-side application such as ASP.NET. I suggest you to take look at [this toolkit](http://www.docentric.com) which we use for document generation in our projects. It supports image/picture placeholders and much more. In case you are unable to use 3rd party libraries in your project, you will need to use Microsoft's Open XML SDK which you can use to parse Word documents (docx). You can implement your own find/replace logic based on OOXM SDK but this will require a lot of learning and effort (in case you are not familiar with Open XML standard and the SDK).